# Inmemory keystore using keystore api 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target'

Tags: java, spring, ssl, ldap, spring-ldap

I am trying to create an inmemory keystore for a single ldap request. Ldap connections and certificates can change so I can't store them anywhere.

Spring Ldap is not very frendly to multiple ldap connections

```java
    public LdapContextSource buildLdapContext(final LdapConnection connection) {
        final LdapContextSource context = new LdapContextSource();
        context.setBase(connection.getBaseDN());
        context.setUrl(connection.getConnectionUrl());
        context.setPassword(connection.getAdminPassword());
        context.setUserDn(connection.getUserDN());

        if(connection.getProtocol() == LdapProtocol.LDAPS) {
            final DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy authenticationStrategy = new DefaultTlsDirContextAuthenticationStrategy();
            authenticationStrategy.setSslSocketFactory(ldapSslSocketFactoryBuilder.buildSslSocketFactory(connection));
            context.setAuthenticationStrategy(authenticationStrategy);
        }

        context.afterPropertiesSet();
        return context;
    }
```

```java
    public SSLSocketFactory buildSslSocketFactory(final LdapConnection connection) {
        try {
            final KeyStore store = buildKeyStore(connection);
            final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(store);

            final SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return ctx.getSocketFactory();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new LdapException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

```java
    private KeyStore buildKeyStore(final LdapConnection ldapConnection) {
        try {
            // Load in-memory keystore
            final KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            keystore.load(null);

            // Decode certificate
            byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(ldapConnection.getSslCertificate()
                            .replaceAll(X509Factory.BEGIN_CERT, "")
                            .replaceAll(X509Factory.END_CERT, "")
                            .trim().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Load certificate
            CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("x.509");
            Certificate cert = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
            keystore.setCertificateEntry(ldapConnection.getConnectionUrl(), cert);

            return keystore;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new LdapException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

I would expect that stored public key is used to connect to ldap server but instead I get "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Comment: Could you please add `-Djavax.net.debug=SSL,handshake,trustmanager` as JVM-Option and check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem. The code works properly, problem was that we were using a self-signed certificated that couldn't be verified. All we had to do was put hte certificate in cacerts file. Self-signed certificates are their own certification authority and as such have to bu placed into cacerts file, the file is located in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts.

Comment: Which in turn means you don't need most of that code.

Comment: We do when using CA signed certificates